# How to limit the number of concurrent Http requests accross asynchronous Celery tasks

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, semaphore

I am crawling many websites asynchronously using Celery tasks ( + python requests and PhantomJs) I use crawlera as a proxy but my account has a limit of 100 concurrent requests.

I am wondering how is the best way to do this. I know I can use Redis (or something else) as a semaphore and re-trigger the task when acquire() fails after a random number of seconds but I think this approach is not good.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this approach is not good? 
It may or may not be good for your situation - it depends entirely on the details of your implementation and your environment.

An alternative approach is to constrain the number of simultaneous connections any 1 worker can make, and constrain the number of workers/tasks so that the total number of connections never exceeds 100.

Comment: I think it's bad because I don't use it for all requests just for some websites, so it would not be optimal

Comment: sorry that's kind of unclear. maybe open a new question showing some sample code - as it is this is all very vague